# Warning after adding siren gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After adding the [siren gem](https://github.com/jcoglan/siren) to my project, it started to give the following warning either running a test or starting rails console:

```
/Users/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@project/gems/methodphitamine-1.0.0/lib/methodphitamine/it_class.rb:14: warning: undefining `object_id' may cause serious problems
/Users/{user}/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@project/gems/methodphitamine-1.0.0/lib/methodphitamine/it_class.rb:14: warning: undefining `__send__' may cause serious problems
```

Does someone had the same problem?

I was looking for a gem who could provide Xpath like features for JSON. If someone know another one, i'll appreciate :)

Thanks

Comment: Are you using ruby 1.9.2?

Comment: Nope. As written in the warning: ruby-2.0.0-p247

Comment: The gem which you are using is pretty old that particular issue was solved a year ago on my fork which you could try to use https://github.com/mitfik/methodphitamine , the problem is related with ruby version and the main project is not compatible with >= 1.9x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That gem is **very** old (last commit over five years ago). For basic JSON parsing you should us Ruby's built-in JSON support.

If you need more complex data structures (I see that Siren provides cross-referencing), maybe another data format like YAML or XML would suit you better.

If you need to use Siren for compatibility reasons, it's probably more compatible with an older version of Ruby.

Comment: I was looking for a gem that gets me Xpath like features for JSON. I've found [this](https://github.com/joshbuddy/jsonpath). Do you know any other?